# Simple edit screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

After some thinking and reworking of my app, I changed my edit screen. What used to happen is that if a user pressed on a row in a form, a view would popup to edit the information of the view. Now I removed that and made one common view to edit any one of the records by choosing it in a picker.

```swift
struct EditBook: View {

    @Binding var bookData: [Book]
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var author = ""
    @State private var page = ""
    @State private var total = ""
    
    @State private var choice = Book(id: UUID(), name: "Dune", author: "Frank Herbert", page: "77", total: "420", image: "String")
    
    var body: some View {
            Form{
                Section{
                    Picker("Choose a book", selection: $choice){
                        ForEach(bookData){b in
                            Text(b.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Change the details of the book")){
                    
                    HStack{
                        Text("Name:")
                        TextField(choice.name, text: $name)
                    }
                    
                    HStack{
                        Text("Author:")
                        TextField(choice.author, text: $author)
                    }
                    
                    HStack{
                        Text("Number of pages:")
                        TextField(choice.total, text: $total)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Change the number of the page you are on")){
                    HStack{
                        Text("Page number:")
                        TextField(choice.page, text: $page)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                }
                Section{
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            let id = choice.id
                            bookData.removeAll(where: { $0.id == choice.id })
                            let temp = Book(id: id, name: name , author: author, page: page, total: total, image: "Image")
                            bookData.insert(temp, at: 0)
                            writeJSON(bookData)
                        }) {
                            Text("Update book")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit Book")
    }
}
```

Note that the button works like this, save the id of the chosen book, delete the chosen book from the array, initialise a new book with the entered information but the same id as the last book, appending the new book to the top of the array and finally encoding the array to json.

The functionality worked in my last edit screen and works to some degree. Right now, any information you enter just creates a new book rather than getting the old one and deleting it.

My guess is that my picker is wrong considering it is taking data from the default Book (dune). The default data is also being shown in the text fields which confirms my suspicions.

Why is my picker not actually passing the chosen data to the text views instead of the declared Book(name: Dune...)?

edit: requested code

```swift
struct Book: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var author: String
    var page: String
    var total: String
    var image: String
}
```

and

```swift
func writeJSON(_ bookData: [Book]) {
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let jsonURL = documentDirectory
        .appendingPathComponent("list")
        .appendingPathExtension("json")
    try? JSONEncoder().encode(bookData).write(to: jsonURL, options: .atomic)
}
```

Note that my load function is called to a member of my content view and the resulting array is bonded to the edit screen.

Comment: Ok, and which is the question?

Comment: @Asperi Sorry why is my picker not actually passing the chosen data to the text views instead of the declared Book(name: Dune...), I am also going to edit the question.

Comment: Could reply some code like `struct Book` and `writeJSON `

Comment: @leorider I edited the code onto the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suggestion.
Replace `@State private var choice` with `@State private var choiceIndex = 0`

and

replace

```
Picker("Choose a book", selection: $choice){
    ForEach(bookData){b in
        Text(b.name)
    }
}
```

with

```
Picker("Choose a book", selection: $choiceIndex){
    ForEach(bookData.indices, id: \.self) { i in
        Text(self.bookData[i].name)
    }
}
```

Maybe it works

Comment: Yep by using the index, everything updated correctly, thanks!